# after render Event on MVC. Possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hy.

I know that there are no server controls and server-side events, but...:

My app is like an email box and the unread items are bold displayed. 
[image]

Ok... the bold items are the unread `(isRead==false)`. I want to update the item to `(isRead=true)` without any click.. just before the page is rendered.

How should I do it? Is there a way in ASP.NET MVC or will I have to do it with JQuery?

.

What is the best way to call a method AFTER "View" rendered?

.

Tks, guys!

Comment: Why would you do that, just because they've been rendered to the screen doesn't mean they've been read.  Also, *read* is an irregular verb in english, past tense of it is also *read*, just pronounced differently.

Comment: I know that. But it isn't exactly an email box. It will only bold display. Nothing more. My English is terrible.. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your english is better than my Portuguese, I assure you.  What view engine are you using, and what version of MVC?

Comment: lol. MVC 3 and Razor view engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally once your action has done it's thing, and you've made it to the view, there's no going back to code (so to speak).  There are two ways to approach this problem.

1. You create a copy of the list of messages to pass to the view and change the original to have `isRead=true`.  I would say this is the preferred way of solving your problem and the code will look something along the lines of:

   ```
   var viewMessages = from m in messages  
                      select new Message  
                      {  
                           // Fields you want to copy go here   
                      }

   viewMessages.ToList(); //This actually creates a list from the query

   // update the isRead property
   foreach( var m in messages ){
        m.isRead = true;
   }
   ```

   You now have two collections, a copy of the original data you can pass to the view to render the data correctly, and the other is your original collection with all items updated with `isRead = true`.
2. The other option isn't as good from the design point of view, but it will be able to accomplish the same goal.  You can put the code to update the property directly into the view, right below where you do the check if it's read or not to change the bold.  I'm assuming your view looks something along the lines of:

   ```
   @foreach(var message in View.Messages) {
      // some code
      <td @(message.isRead ? " class=\"selected\"" : null)
          message.Heading
          @{ message.isRead = true; } // Set it as read once it's been rendered
      </td>
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to update the view, you can either change the model before passing it to the view, or you can use jQuery to modify the DOM after the page has been loaded into the browser.

On the other hand, if you are trying to change the model (and persist it as having been read), you can either update the model when you query for it *before* passing the model to the view, or you can use JavaScript (jQuery) to hit a link on your server telling you to mark those entries at read.

However, as R0MANARMY stated, just because someone has glanced at the title of your entry, does not mean that they have acknowledged it's existence.

This could be accomplished by opening a link to the individual entry to see the details of that entry, and have your logic mark the individual item as read at that time.

Hope this is helpful :)